# Error FFMPEG when convert video to MP4 with baseline presset

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have this command in ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i '/var/www/sites/default/files/private/videos/original/reel para web en loop_2_2.mp4' -vf 'scale=640:480' -strict experimental -vco
dec 'h264' -vpre 'libx264-baseline' -acodec 'aac' -vprofile 'baseline' -ac '2'
 -y /tmp/1379483589-52393fc5e233e.mp4
```

And I have the following pressets:

```
libvpx-1080p50_60.ffpreset  libvpx-720p50_60.ffpreset  libx264-ipod320.ffpreset
libvpx-1080p.ffpreset       libvpx-720p.ffpreset       libx264-ipod640.ffpreset
libvpx-360p.ffpreset        libx264-baseline.ffpreset
```

And this is the result:

```
ffmpeg version N-56279-g5295407 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 15 2013 03:43:12 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame
--enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-
libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      52. 43.100 / 52. 43.100
  libavcodec     55. 31.101 / 55. 31.101
  libavformat    55. 16.102 / 55. 16.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 84.100 /  3. 84.100
  libswscale      2.  5.100 /  2.  5.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/sites/default/files/private/vi
deos/original/reel para web en loop_2_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2013-09-12 17:30:22
  Duration: 00:00:39.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3190 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 720x4
80 [SAR 40:33 DAR 20:11], 2991 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn, 59.94 tbc
(default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-09-12 17:30:22
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 18
9 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-09-12 17:30:22
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
[NULL @ 0xab9d980] [Eval @ 0xbfd87b9c] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'wpr
ed'
[NULL @ 0xab9d980] Unable to parse option value "wpred-dct8x8"
[NULL @ 0xab9d980] Error setting option flags2 to value -wpred-dct8x8.
Output #0, mp4, to '/tmp/1379483589-52393fc5e233e.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 15:11 DAR 20:11], q=-1-
-1, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-09-12 17:30:22
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-09-12 17:30:22
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters
such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

What is the problem in my command? I have baseline profile in ffmpeg. Or I need do one more step?
I need that this file playing in iPhone in MP4. Because I use JW Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like an actual issue with the scripts in the preset vs your build of FFMpeg.  It appears that the syntax of options being passed to the encoder are incorrect (particularly something related to "wpred" and a missing parens) and since they are not specified in your command line, I can only assume it is the preset that is the problem.  I would suggest trying either a different version, a different build or a different source for your copy of FFMPEG and see if you have better luck.

Comment: So, I need download other version of FFMPEG and rebuild.

Comment: @Dvex - that's my best guess given the error.  I could be wrong though.  I don't have any specific experience with FFMPEG, but I'm a software developer in general and the error seems to indicate that the profile being used doesn't match with the build or is simply corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `-vpre 'libx264-baseline'`. This preset should not be included with your ffmpeg build and is designed for older builds; therefore resulting in usage of unsupported, old options. I am guessing you copied the old preset file from somewhere are tried to get a newer ffmpeg to use it.

Using `-vprofile 'baseline'` should suffice.

See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) and [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for more info.